# How to download magnet or torrent file in react native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, torrent

Is there a way for downloading and saving torrent files in react native? I tried using react-native-torrent-streamer but it doesn't work anymore with the latest version of react native. So is there another way to do it?

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-torrent-streamer npm package , but i works only in android.

Comment: React native torrent streamer doesn't with the latest version of react native

Comment: You can also use [webtorrent.io](https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent) library it's a great tool for saving or streaming magnets or even `.torrent` files

Comment: Webtorrent doesnt work with react native since its a nodejs package

Answer (score -1):

Since that module is merely a thin wrapper around https://github.com/TorrentStream/TorrentStream-Android and that library seems to work, I would suggest you open the android folder from the module within node_modules & update the TorrentStream-Android version and see if that works. Otherwise, replace the code from the RN module with a working test of TorrentStream-Android and work from there.